# htaccess redirect showing 404 not found error for jpg file

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have some simple URL like this

```
/sub/image.jpg
/sub/sub/sub/image.jpg
```

I want to redirect them to another page but when I use redirect code this page giving 404 error.

```
Redirect 301 /sub/1.jpg https://examplel.com/new-page
```

FYI: those images are not on my server now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this generic redirect :

```
RedirectMatch 404 ^/.*sub.+\.jpg$
```

Comment: I need to redirect specific pages, not 404 pages.

Comment: @Mi2  It only redirects specific pages to 404

Answer (score 1):

You may also try this rule that matches any URI that starts with `/sub/` and is not a file or directory:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^sub/ https://examplel.com/new-page [L,NC,R=302]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your `mod_rewrite` rules.